# Create Headers Type Named Value in Api Management Service Backend

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform, azure-api-management

I tried to create a credential headers type Named Value from PowerShell or Terraform but only allow me to create those headers type [manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/new-azurermapimanagementbackendcredential?view=azurermps-6.13.0).
exist any way to create this kind of header using PowerShell or Terraform ?

Comment: You can create credential object by using powershell and your linked article states it exactly how. What is the problem you are getting?

Azure's article in your questions link is explaining about creating a particular type of credential to configure a backend, for example function apps or logic app. What is your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

$cred = Get-Credential

The above line creates a Named Value pair for credential in powershell

[image]